# Redshift COPY from S3 fails when timestamp is not correct

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

While loading data into Redshift from S3 via the COPY command, if any record in the file contains an incorrect timestamp, then the copy fails. I have passed maxerror as 1000 to the COPY command, but still it fails.

However, upon subsequent retries, the same command works. Though it fails to load the corrupted records.

This is the error I am getting:

```
ERROR:  Assert
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   status == 0 - timestamp: '-6585881136298398395'
  query:     30903
  location:  cg_util.cpp:1063
  process:   query1_69 [pid=25674]
  -----------------------------------------------

AWS cli version : aws-cli/1.10.56 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.4.19-29.55.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.4.46
```

Is there anyone who faced the same issue? How did you resolve it?

Comment: One trick you can do is to load the timestamp field as a string, then use an UPDATE command to populate a timestamp column based on the string.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am fine with the corrupt record(record containing wrong timestamp) not getting loaded to redshift. But other records should be loaded, and I think setting maxerror argument in copy command to a certain value should handle this. But I don't see the behaviour consistent, sometimes the data loads, sometimes it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append

```
ACCEPTANYDATE dateformat 'auto'
```

in your copy statement.

[**ACCEPTANYDATE**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-acceptanydate/)
[**dateformat**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-dateformat/)
(AWS Documentation)

This'll atleast try to enforce that your copy statements don't fail. Still, some of the unsupported format might be null (as you mentioned,*I am fine with the corrupt record(record containing wrong timestamp) not getting loaded to redshift. But other records should be loaded*)

Comment: I am using timeformat 'auto'. As per the document, aws is suggesting to use ACCEPTANYDATE with dateformat, and not with timeformat. Thanks, will try it out.

Comment: Thanks :) Also, do upvote and let others know if it worked.

Comment: Sure, I still have one doubt. Why is maxerror not handling this?, Did you face the exact same issue with maxerror?